# Why is my internet connection so slow?

Tags: network, wifi, internet

I have an issue with my internet connection where some web sites (including google.com) are sometimes really slow.

My internet connection is optic-fiber, very stable, ping to 8.8.8.8 without any error all-day long:

[image]

When I access the internet from my Windows machine, all web pages load very stable and fast.

When I access the internet from my Mac (same WiFi), some web pages are very slow some of the time. This happens both in Safari and Chrome, I always test both.

I was able to catch the last occurrence in Chrome console:

[image: Chrome console]

During the time I was recoding Chrome console above, YouTube was playing music non-stop, I was communicating with Messages and e-mail.

Any ideas where can I start debugging?

Comment: It shows a Status 301 'moved permanently', which would suggest a redirect error [possibly HTTP to HTTPS]. I'd start by returning to your ISP's default DNS.

Comment: Good idea about DNS, I'm using my and that uses my IPS's DNS, I will try switching to ISP or `8.8.8.8` directly.